# Class Based View to get user authentication in Django

Tags: python, django, class, authentication, request

Ok, have a class based view that passes a `query_set` into my `AssignedToMe` class. The point of this class based view is to see if a user is logged in and if they are, they can go to a page and it will display all of records that are assigned to their ID. Currently, it is working how I want it to but only if a user is logged in. If a user is not logged in, I get the following error `'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`.
I want it to redirect the user to the login page if there is no user logged in. Thank you in advance. Please look at the screenshot

Comment: Are you using [@login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator? If yes, do you have the `LOGIN_URL` defined in your `settings.py`

Comment: Yes, I tried using the @login_required and that was not working either, kept getting 'AssignToMe' has not object 'user'

Answer (score 1):

You can create a login required mixin to use in your ClassBasedViews like this:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then use it like @M. Gara suggests (it should be the first thing). Also make sure you have the `LOGIN_URL` defined in your `settings.py`

Reference: [decorating the class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)

Alternatively you can choose to [decorate the url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-in-urlconf).

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whats the context of your ClassBasedView ... but you can use the LoginRequiredMixin to require the login before calling your class :

`class ServerDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Server
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ui:dashboard')`